# TCL: Build static library in Windows

Tags: dll, compilation, tcl, static-libraries

I am trying to compile TCL source code in windows7 so that I can get static libraries in my build files (instead of .dll). I followed steps in [this page](https://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/compile.html) , so I used the following command to compile the TCL source

```
nmake -f makefile.vc OPTS=static INSTALLDIR=path_to_your_install_dir
nmake -f makefile.vc install OPTS=static INSTALLDIR=path_to_your_install_dir
```

but actually I can't find any ".a" generated file. If I removed "OPTS=static", I can get ".dll" file but this is I don't need.

So does anyone know how to get this static library?

Comment: It might be called `tcl86.lib` on Windows, if I remember right? (I haven't used that platform for development for a long time…)

Comment: @DonalFellows , because I don't have much experience with sw development, how to check that .lib is the one that I am searching for. (BTW, I compiled the source code in linux and I can get .a file). So how to know that .lib is equivalent to .a file please?.. thanks a lot for your help

Comment: When building a library on *Win* (*VStudio*) you'll always get a *.lib* file. If building a static one this will be the only file of interest, and it will be quite large, while when building a dynamic one you'll also get a *.dll* (and the *.lib* will be smaller). *.lib* is the (*Nix*'s) *.a* equivalent.

Comment: correct .. thank you all.